# scheduling a task on a particular date/date-range using cron4j

Tags: java, scheduler, job-scheduling

I am using cron4j for scheduling email alerts as selected by the user on daily, weekly and monthly basis between the specified dates.

I am unable to find the pattern to schedule a task on particular date/dates. Say for example an email should be triggered from 15-07-2012 to 18-07-2012 daily at 11:59 pm.

The problem i am facing there is no year field in cron4j as far as i know and thus how to schedule a task on particular date or date range.

Answer (score 0):

> 15-07-2012 to 18-07-2012 daily at 11:59 pm

59 23 15-18 7 *

cron4j seems to work like a regular cron. See [docs](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/manual.php).

You can add an if-statement inside the Runnable to check for the specific year.